# how to get rounded dialog theme for activity

Tags: android

I need to create a activity which should look like as a dialog box with a rounded corners.

For this requirement I set

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Now my activity looks like a dialog box but I need its corners to be rounded.

Then I created  xml with  attribute and set this drawable as my activity theme but now my activity not looks like dialog box.

Please suggest me what can be done so that my  activity looks like dialog box with rounded corners.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could make your own `theme` that has rounded corners. First you'll need a `drawable` for the `Activity` background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

    <solid android:color="#565656" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="6dp"
        android:left="6dp"
        android:right="6dp"
        android:top="3dp" />

</shape>
```

Next make your own theme that extends the parent `Theme.Dialog`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="ThemeWithCorners" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/another_test_drawable</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

This will be in a file named `styles.xml` in the `res/values` folder. Use this theme in the android manifest for the `Activity` you want:

```
//...
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityName"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeWithCorners" >
//...
```

Comment: please my dear does your answer can be applied to ice cream sandwish alertdialog , i try but it doesnt work , cant get round corner ,thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip to use a theme. Just setting the drawable as the background didn't make the corner bits transparent.

Comment: add this to remove the white patch at corners of this activity. <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

Answer (score 0):

First, create a rounded corner shape drawable like so:

dialogbg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Then, go to the layout xml file for your activity, and change it's android:backgorund attribute like so

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="..." 
    android:layout_height="..." 
    android:background="@drawable/dialogbg">
    <!--views here...-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Saarraz , Thanks for your help but I tried the above solution , Its modifying the shape of layout but not the actual activity.

Answer (score 0):

If for anyone the above answer is not working try to do this:

Need to create a round shape first like any of the above examples:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <corners android:radius="8dp" /> </shape>`

1.Set this shape to the layout of your activity.
2.Create a custom style like below:`

```
<style name="mycustomtheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

`

Now set the theme in your activity
`<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/mycustomtheme" >`