# How do I change the shape of a dialog?

Tags: android, background, dialog

In my app I use many dialogs (popups) and I want to give them a rounded corner shape.

The way I create these popups is this:

On java code I create a function like this:

```
private void showpopup(){

   dialog = new Dialog(this);
   dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   dialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null));
   dialog.setCancelable(false);



    TextView fin = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.solu);
    fin.setText("¡¡safsfasfsafs!!");  


   fin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               dialog.dismiss();
               }

   });   
  dialog.show();
}
```

The layout I call there is created in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
  >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" 
        >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/solu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and finally, the xml "shape" that I call in the background is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="20dp"/>

<stroke
android:width="1dp"
android:color="@color/black"/>

</shape>
```

The result it's something like this:

[image]

As you can see, I don't achieve what I want...

Comment: You may want to set the window background instead of the layout background.

Comment: I changed  android:background="@drawable/shape" for  android:windowbackground="@drawable/shape", error in code, is not allowed :S:

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'windowbackground' in package 'android'

Comment: That's not how one changes the window background. If you want to do it from XML then you need to define a theme. Otherwise, just do `getWindow().setBackgroundX()`

Comment: Don't understand what you mean, where I have to do that and how?

Comment: `dialog.getWindow().setBackground...()` at `showpopup`

Answer (score 7):

Try to use my answer from here: [how to get rounded dialog theme for activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072045/how-to-get-rounded-dialog-theme-for-activity/10072780#10072780) (It's the same thing with what you're trying to do). Create a custom theme(make a reference to your own shape drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="ThemeWithCorners" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/another_test_drawable</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

(this will be in `res/themes.xml`). Then simple add the theme to the constructor of the `Dialog`:

```
dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.ThemeWithCorners);
```