# Change the Theme.Dialog style

Tags: android, themes

[image]

In my application i am using set alarm activity.When i press the setalarm button it show alarm activity as Theme.Dialog format.
    My problem is this theme visible only few buttons with collapsed format.I need theme as a rounded rectangle with slight bigger size thanks...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tw_taskid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Task Name:"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewdis_listname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/textviewdateid"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnid_date"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="@string/changedate" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnid_time"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnid_changetime"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="ChangeTime" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_setalarm"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="Set-Alarm" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_CancelAlarm"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="Cancel-Alarm" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use RelativeLayout for positioning items.

And use ***Shape*** tag to provide rounded corners to your Dialog View.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dip" />
</shape>
```

Refer link: [how to get rounded dialog theme for activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072045/how-to-get-rounded-dialog-theme-for-activity)